# onProgressUpdate in Async is not being called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

im having problems with my progressdialog and(for now) it all stops when my async threads onProgressUpdate() never gets called.
The onPreExecute() and doInBackground() runs just fine, but i cannot for the life of me get the onProgressUpdate() function to start :(
the code is mostly taken from her: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

and here is my version of the code:

```js
private class createPasswordList2 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
  
  @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         Log.v(logtag,"In async: onPreExecute...");
         //ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Wait", "Downloading...");
         //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Decrypting, Please wait...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         pDialog.setMax(100);
         pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
         pDialog.show();
     }
  @Override
      protected Long doInBackground(String... foo) {
          int count =20;
          long totalSize = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           try{
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           }catch(Exception e) {
                     Log.v(logtag, e.getMessage());
                 }
              totalSize +=1;
              Log.v(logtag,"async2...doInBackground");
              publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
              // Escape early if cancel() is called
              if (isCancelled()) break;
          }
          return totalSize;
      }
      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
       String logtag="";
       Log.v(logtag,"async2...onProgressUpdate");
       pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
      
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
       Log.v(logtag,"async2...onPostExecute");
       pDialog.dismiss();
         // showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
      }
  }
```

the program executes the doInBackground() function and prints the log lines, but the screen on the phone turns black and never changes. Ive search the entire (i am sure...) internet for people with my problem, but none of the proposed solutions seems to work.

Any and all help appriciated

kenneth

Comment: Why are you calling `Thread.sleep(1000);`?

Comment: it was an attempt to slow things down which i was hoping would help me spot the problem. but it didnt :(

Comment: are you sure about the value being more than 100 ? faik the first iteration i get: publishProgress((int) ((0 / (float) count) * 100)) which resolves to 0. !?

Comment: Can you post your whole Activity?  I just tried this code and it works fine, even with the `Thread.sleep()`.  I saw the progress getting updated just fine, and the dialog gets dismissed afterwards and it goes back to the Activity.  One more question though, where do you define `logtag`?